# Missing intent 'extras' values after reboot

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I just found out that I don't know how to save my Intent extras after device reboot. I need it for shedule notifications.

Here is part in **MainActivity** where I set alarm

```java
Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            startTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            long alarmStartTime = startTime.getTimeInMillis();

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra("notificationId", notificationId);
            intent.putExtra("text", text);
            intent.putExtra("alarmStartTime", alarmStartTime);
            intent.setAction("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED");
            intent.setAction("android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON");

            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);


            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmStartTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

**AlarmReceiver**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null){
        int notificationId = extras.getInt("notificationId");
        String message = extras.getString("text");

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(action) ||
                QUICKBOOT_POWERON.equals(action)) {

            Intent service = new Intent(context, BootService.class);
            service.setAction(message);
            service.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            service.putExtra("notificationId", notificationId);
            service.putExtra("text", message);
            context.startService(service);
        }
    }
}
```

Methods from **BootService** where I need to get notificationId and message

```
private void setAlarm(int Id, String message) {
    Context context = MyApp.getContext();
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    mainIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED");
    mainIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON");

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mainIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationManager myNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .setContentTitle("Wake up! " + Id)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    myNotificationManager.notify(Id, builder.build());
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    int Id = intent.getExtras().getInt("notificationId", 0);
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("text");
    setAlarm(Id, message);
    Context context = MyApp.getContext();
    Intent service = new Intent(context, BootService.class);
    stopService(service);
}
```

Everything works fine but after reboot my extras are null. Thanks.

Comment: to avoid that you can use shared preferences and get value from there after reboot.

Comment: @Umair, thank you, I thought about that too. But where should I use shared preferences?

Comment: you should use them at first where you are sending your data through intent. and when you are receiving extras make an if else statement which will check if the device is rebooted then take value from shared preferences other it will work as it is.

Comment: one more thing can you tell which notification Id you want to get when your device is rebooted 
1) In your AlarmReceiver you are setting one 
2) In your mainActivity you are setting one too.

Comment: @Umair, I set random notification id in MainActivity and then just use it

Comment: well then save your notification Id there and only get it if your device is rebooted. and don't forget to update notification ID whenever it is generated.

Comment: @Umair, the problem that I'll have several notifications with different id, so I don't know how to get correct key of shared preference. I found out that I lose my extras in BootService so how can I get right key of my notification id?

Comment: Only way to get your notifications ID is if you save them in either database or shared pref it's upto you. As you said restarting your phone would remove all your extras. So either change your logic or save your data :)

Comment: Did you ever figure out the best way to handle this situation?  I am stuck with a similar situation and have not come across a good way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to permanent save some data you can create for example a **HasMap** that contains all your extra value

```
Map<String,String> extras = new HasMap<Strimg,String>();
extras.put("notificationId", notificationId);
extras.put("text",text);
.
.
```

And every time you update some value, you can serialize this Map saving it on a file that will be always available even after reboot

Serialize and save

```
FileOutputStream fos =new FileOutputStream("hashmap.ser");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(extras);
oos.close();
fos.close();
```

Finally when you first run your app after reboot you will associate at your Map extras the object stored in the serialized file

Restore Hasmap

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("hashmap.ser");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
extras = (HashMap) ois.readObject();
ois.close();
fis.close();
```